# Disallowing path with parameter

Tags: seo, robots.txt, url-parameters, disallow

I found a loads of examples where in **robots.txt** were disallowed urls with similar approaches:

`Disallow: /*?dir=*&order=*&p=*`

Where every path with specified parameters will be blocked.

What if I want to block an urls with a specified path? Lets say I want to block:
`/Home/SomeBlockedPath?dir=false&order=desc&p=12` and have allowed: `/Home/AllowedPath?dir=false&order=desc&p=3`. Is this approach below fine?

`Disallow: /Home/SomeBlockedPath?dir=*&order=*&p=*`

Answer (score 3):

All right, I found an answer in docs for how to use robots.txt:

[URL matching based on path values](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt?csw=1#url-matching-based-on-path-values)
[Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt?csw=1#devsite-thumb-label-header:%7E:text=feedback-,Robots.txt%20Specifications)

This should be fine:

`Disallow: /Home/SomeBlockedPath`

Comment: That looks a lot better.   The major search engines support the wildcards in robots.txt rules, but most other crawlers don't.     Avoid wildcards by using simple prefix rules like this when possible.

Comment: Using multiple wildcards is problematic even for bots that support wildcards.   Your original rule disallows specific parameters used in a particular order.   But change the order of the parameters and search engines would be able to crawl.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Do you think, that `Disallow: /Home/SomeBlockedPath` is better than `Disallow: /Home/SomeBlockedPath*` in my case?

Comment: Without the asterisk is better.   The two rules are the same for the bots that support wildcards, but there are a lot of bots that won't understand the rule with the wildcard.

Comment: Great, thank you for comments. SEO is still a black magic to me ;)